# Form Code and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Thanks for answering my previous query but I've been halted again since I don't know what I'm missing or where I'm wrong. Here is the HTML form I made:

```
  <div class="container">
   <span class="reg"> <h1>Register Now</h1> </span>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="conent-part">
       <div class="form-body">
        <div class="fome-body">
          <form id="form" action="/sendform.php" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-part">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nname" id="nname" placeholder="Nominee's Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="nemail" id="nemail" placeholder="Nominee's Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-part">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nsport" id="nsport" placeholder="Nominee's Sport">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="accomplishments" id="accomplishments" placeholder="Accomplishments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="custom_btn">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the sendform.php code that I just made but it won't post, it just goes to sendform.php blank page.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $nname = $_POST['nname'];
    $nemail = $_POST['nemail'];
    $nsport = $_POST['nsport'];
    $message = $_POST['accomplishments'];
    $from = $from = $email;
    $to = 'tempbiz@mail-central.com'; 
    $subject = 'Athlete of the Week - Nomination';

    $body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Nominee's Name: $nname\n Nominee's Email: $nemail\n Nominee's Nominee's Sport: $nsport\n Accomplishments:\n $accomplishments";
?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your Nomination has been Successfully Sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your Nomination again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: do you have errors/warnings turned up?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, there's no error.txt generated or any error at all. When I click the Submit button it goes to /sendform.php which is just a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whatever the browser added the submit name to the `POST` data.

Change:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: This one worked out! Thanks.

Comment: @Tempbiz, You can feel free to upvote this answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no input named 'submit' in your form, so your mail sending block is never executed. You have to add a 'submit' input. I.e:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
```

Comment: Oh! I'll try it where should I put it? Under the "<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>" ?

Comment: Anywhere inside the form.